# Como atualizar estado global do Redux em uma aplicação React depois de fazer um post na API?

Tags: react, redux

Um formulário em React que você entra com nome e texto.

A aplicação usa estado global Redux, ele puxa uma API com axios e faz um post na API com os dados do formulário.

Quando faço um novo post quero atualizar o estado global para mostrar a postagem na tela sem ter que carregar a pagina, só que não estou conseguindo. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que me parece seu problema esta no seu reducer, mais especificamente nesse trecho:

```
 case TypesPost.NEW_POST:

        const newPost = state.arrayPost
        newPost.push(action.payload)

        return{
          arrayPost: newPost
        }
```

quando você faz um `const newPost = state.arrayPost` você esta realizando uma atribuição por referência, logo quando você faz um `push` em `newPost` você esta mutando o estado atual do seu reducer, e ao tentar atualizar o estado em:

```
        return{
          arrayPost: newPost
        }
```

a referência se mantem a mesma, então muito provavelmente por mais que seu array tenha um indice a mais, essa alteração de estado não é indentificada, logo os componentes não são notificados.

sugiro que você altere seu reducer deixando ele dessa forma:

```
 case TypesPost.NEW_POST:

        const newPost = [...state.arrayPost, action.payload]

        return{
          arrayPost: newPost
        }
```

dessa forma um novo array será gerado com o novo post.

Comment: Obrigado Gabriel, você é um gênio, obrigado peça dica e pela explicação. Vou fazer uma outra pergunta sobre Redux de uma outra duvida que surgiu, se você puder ver e me ajudar. Mas obrigado mesmo.